# Wcf не могу менять данные

Tags: c#, wcf

Доброго времени суток. Начал разбираться с `wcf`. начал с стандартных примеров - математических действий, но чуть усложнив задачу  столкнулся с проблемой, не получается изменять данные.

Есть  интерфейс

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IScoreboard
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetCount();

    [OperationContract]
    int AddLine(string line, bool weather);

    [OperationContract]
    int DeleteLine(int _id);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetLine(int _id);

}
```

Есть класс

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceScoreboard  : IScoreboard
{

    public Line[] note = new Line[24];
    public int _id = 0;

    public int GetCount()
    {

        return _id;
    }

    public int AddLine(string line, bool weather)
    {

        if (_id < 24)
        {
            Line lineToAdd = new Line(line, weather);
            lineToAdd.SetId(_id);
            note[_id] = lineToAdd;
            _id++;
           return _id; 
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public string GetLine(int _id)
    {
        return note[_id].GetLine();
    }

}
```

---

проблема была в том что не мог менять значения свойств класса 
[[@petya](/users/7207/petya)](/users/7207/petya) спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

И поскольку теперь это ответ, стоит написать подробнее:

ServiceBehaviorAttribute указывает когда создается объект wcf сервиса

PerSession - сервис создается для каждой сессии клиента

PerCall - для вызова каждого метода (соответственно, никакого состояния сервис хранить не будет)

Single - один сервис для всех клиентов